# properly structuring an htaccess with multiple rules/conds

Tags: php, .htaccess

How would i properly structure this htaccess file as to correctly function in order and avoid infinite loops?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^deviceToken/$ devicetoken.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register/$ register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^resetPassword/$ resetpassword.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^deleteLink/$ deletelink.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^getLinks/$ getlinks.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)|(\.swf)|(\.xpi)|(\.ico)|(\.src)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ get.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Define "correctly function"  :)

Comment: what would be an alternative?

Comment: hey what are you doing? Why deleting your questions? Stop that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK, have you tried it already?

This line is useless:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
```

Redirect domain first:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(added `,L`)

Comment: yeah, when i visit domain.com, instead of redirecting to www.domain.com, it redirects to http://www.domain.com/get.php?code=http://www.domain.com/